# Adding c# file with global variables and helper functions without adding a web page with it

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, global-variables

i'm new to asp.net and will appriciate if you can help me with that:
I'm using VS and I want to add a C# file that will include some global variables and helper functions that I'll use on different pages.
I don't see any option to add a standalone file (VS 2013) without adding a web page with it.
How can I add such a file and how do I call its' functions and global variables from other pages C# files?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can Create `Common.cs` as Class to Save Your Global Variables in `App_Code` Folder in Your Asp.net Application.

```
public class Common
{
    public Common()
    {
        //
        // TODO: Add constructor logic here
        //
    }
   private static string MyValue;

   public static string MyMethod()
   {

      return "My String";

   }

}
```

//calling

```
string Mystr=Common.MyMethod();
```

EDIT:

[image: Screent Shot]

Comment: I dont see such folder, the only generated folders in my website are App_Data and aspnet_client. When I'm right clicking -> add I have these options: "new virtual directory", "webform", "web user control", "javascript file", "style sheet". none of them seems to create the standalone c# file

Comment: @Ira See the Updated Screen Shot

Comment: It seems like we are not using the same versions of VS - this is how it looks on my version: http://snag.gy/OHYZV.jpg

Comment: "new virtual directory" shouldn't show up in a normal ASP.NET application. This smells of Web Pages or something. @Ira: do describe carefully how you created your project.

Comment: Ohhhh! I was running an emulator in vs - once I stopped it I'm able to see the above options. Thaks and sorry for that. one last question, how do I call the newly created global functions from one of the existing pages?